# QT migration 5.9 to 5.10 cameraviewfinder broken

Tags: c++, qt, camera, raspberry-pi3

Environment A: cross-compiling on Ubuntu to Raspberry pi3 in source dir

```
~/src/rpi2point/qt-everywhere-opensource-src-5.9.0-rc2$ ~/src/rpi2point/qt-everywhere-opensource-src-5.9.0-rc2/configure -release -opengl es2  -device linux-rasp-pi3-vc4-g++ -device-option CROSS_COMPILE=~/src/rpi2point/tools/arm-bcm2708/gcc-linaro-arm-linux-gnueabihf-raspbian-x64/bin/arm-linux-gnueabihf- -sysroot ~/src/rpi2point/sysroot -opensource -confirm-license -make libs -no-use-gold-linker -no-pch -prefix /usr/local/qt5pi -extprefix ~/src/rpi2point/qt5pi -hostprefix ~/src/rpi2point/qt5 -v
```

QML Video Shader Effect and QML Video Example working

Camera Example throws:

```
/home/matin/src/rpi2point/sysroot/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libQt5OpenGL.so.5:-1: error: undefined reference to `operator delete(void*, unsigned int)@CXXABI_1.3.9'
/home/matin/src/rpi2point/sysroot/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libQt5OpenGL.so.5:-1: error: undefined reference to `qTriangulate(QVectorPath const&, QTransform const&, double)@Qt_5_PRIVATE_API'
```

Environment B: cross-compiling on Ubuntu to Raspberry pi3 in source dir

- `mkdir qt5.10`
- `git clone https://github.com/qt/qt5.git`
- `./init-repository`
- `./configure -release -opengl es2  -device linux-rasp-pi3-vc4-g++ -device-option CROSS_COMPILE=~/src/rpi2point/tools/arm-bcm2708/gcc-linaro-arm-linux-gnueabihf-raspbian-x64/bin/arm-linux-gnueabihf- -sysroot ~/src/rpi2point/sysroot -opensource -confirm-license -make libs -no-use-gold-linker -no-pch -prefix /usr/local/qt5pi -extprefix ~/src/rpi2point/qt5pi -hostprefix ~/src/rpi2point/qt5 -v`

Reconfigure QtCreator with additional device and building for qt 5.10 - the examples compile and run -- but no picture from the camera

any sugestions?

THX Martin

Comment: Ensure that you using stable version. And be better if you'll not use self builded Qt set. Because 3rd party builds from repositories can tests better than you.

Comment: Then pls point me to an appropriate build

Comment: From your title I assume it worked with Qt 5.9? Have you tried both configuration with 5.9 as well?